# How to get other form fields not just files when using FileUploader library in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data

I have a multipart/form-data with 2 fields: file and select

```
<form id="myform" action="/upload-files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="files" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="targetLanguage">
      What is the target language?
    </label>
    <select id="targetLanguage" name="targetLanguage" autocomplete="targetLanguage">
      <option>Ukrainian</option>
      <option>English</option>
      <option>Russian</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

The form is handled by the [FileUploader](https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/documentation/) library. While it successfully handles the files I can't get the values from the select field. I use NodeJS. Here how I handle the form on the backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fileuploader = require('fileuploader');

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    
    var uploader = fileuploader('files', {
        maxSize: 15,
        uploadDir: 'uploads/'
    }, req, res);
    
    // call to process the form (req.body) and to upload the files
    uploader.upload(async function(data) {

        if (data.isSuccess) {
            
            var files = data.files;
            //for brevity I cut unrelated code 
            
            res.redirect('/calculation-result/');
        } else {
            var warnings = data.warnings;
            console.log(warnings);
            res.send('Upload error');
        }
        res.end()
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to use multer and parse the req.body. This way I can get the fields, but then the FileUploader is not working - its data.files is an empty array.

I checked all the documentation for FileUploader but haven't found any examples with other form fields except files.

I even thought to make two separate forms (one for files and one for select) and trigger them with one button. But it adds a lot of complication as I use database and need to make calculations with both fields.

May be some of you have any experience with FileUploader and can suggest any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the first thing try to add `mode='no-cors'` inside your form tag,

if you still have a problem with that try to use `Fromdata`

```
        Form = document.getElementsById('myform')
        From.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>
        var data = new FormData()
        data.append('YourFile',Form.files.files[0]);
        data.append('YourIput',Form.targetLanguage.value);
        
         //then send the data using Fetch API
         fetch('/upload-files', {
         method : 'POST',
         body :  data ,
         headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
         mode : 'no-cors'
         })

         )

         //Now in the back-end , let's get the data
         const file = req.files.YourFile;
         const input = req.body.YourIput;
          
         console.log(file) //--> to show the method that your file contains like (mv,size,...)
         
          //if you still have problems let me know.

          //i'm using express-fileupload , try it's a good library,
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts. That heavy lifting is done by library, it has a lot of options, messages etc, and styled front end. I will try to get the other field value by figuring out how to use library and multer, just need to remove conflict. Because seems like multer is stealing the files from FileUploader

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. FileUploader can parse the req.body by itself.

Previously I tried to req.body before initialising the uploader and the result was undefined.

But if we use req.body inside uploader function - it works as expected.

```
uploader.upload(async function(data) {
        var lang = req.body.targetLanguage;
...
```